# Progressively adding to a list

Tags: python

Take the `list` variable `num1 = []`

and say i also take `num1_child = randint(0,100)`

how do I go about making `num1` progressively become a longer list by adding `num1_child` to the list, as opposed to simply changing it's value every eteration?

*(I looked at: [Adding integers progressively to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653781/adding-integers-progressively-to-a-list) but did not fully understand how to implement that in my code)*

Comment: How long do you want your ```num1``` to be ? You could just append ```num1_child``` to ```num1```

Comment: Do you know about the `.append()` method of lists?

Comment: I'd call the list `num` or `nums` instead of `num1`, which would wrongly suggest it was a single number rather than a list. Also, rather than saying "adding" to a list, you mean "appending".

Comment: @L3viathan @smci I did not know that was a thing! Thank you very much. I'll look up the documentation for `.append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to add 10 nums into the list, then you can achieve by using simple looping.
Also You can change to whatever number you want and specify the parameter in the **range()** method.

```
>>> for i in range(10):
    nums.append(random.randint(0, 100))

    
>>> nums
[45, 97, 67, 40, 6, 18, 85, 19, 18, 76]
>>>
```

Comment: is that not what `.extend()` would give you?